# Android Billing library: Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError No static method

Tags: android, proguard, nosuchmethoderror, android-billing

We're using a [library](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/blob/master/gdx-pay-android-googlebilling) that depends on `com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1`, and got these crashes for the SHIELD device. How can this issue be resolved?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError No static method
>   a(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;
>   in class Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub; or
>   its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)

Stack trace

```
com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$BillingServiceConnection.onServiceConnected (BillingClientImpl.java:822)
android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1634)
android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1663)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6565)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This is the relevant code in the Android Billing library 1.1

```
@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
      BillingHelper.logVerbose(TAG, "Billing service connected.");

      mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service); // Line 822 where it crashes
      String packageName = mApplicationContext.getPackageName();
      mSubscriptionsSupported = false;
      mSubscriptionUpdateSupported = false;
      mIABv6Supported = false;
      // The code below tries to figure out, which IAB API version and features are supported by
      // current client (Play Store app on this device).
      // First, it checks for IABv6 with subscriptions to avoid extra queries for most of the
      // clients.
      // Second, it checks if IABv6 is supported for in-app only items.
      // Third, it checks for IABv5 for subscription only (since only getBuyIntentToReplaceSku was
      // added during that release).
      // And finally it checks for IABv3 for both subscriptions and inapp items.
      try {
        // Check for in-app billing API v6 support with subscriptions. This is needed for
        // getPurchaseHistory and getBuyIntentExtraParams methods.
        @BillingResponse
        int response = mService.isBillingSupported(/* apiVersion */ 6, packageName, SkuType.SUBS);
```

Comment: you'll probably have to post your code. you'll probably have to provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I put it the stack trace and the relevant codepath where it crashes

Comment: are you using proguard?